# installing fuse-python on windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, 64-bit, fuse

I'm getting this error egg:info error

```
Collecting fuse-python
  Using cached fuse-python-1.0.5.tar.gz (49 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      The system cannot find the path specified.
      The system cannot find the path specified.
      pkg-config unavailable, build terminated
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

I did try to make this install from Pypi site.
after a closer look i've found that egg_info file is almost empty no version info.
how to solve it......Thanks for your time.

Comment: It looks like this library may only be supported for posix systems, not windows

Comment: Even installing from the file downloaded directly or by any means the meta info is still missing do not know how to bypass this problem or solve it.

Comment: It's meant for windows and it can not be not for windows for one reason it's about a game made for windows originally thanx for your help. C.Nis